# Sound Issue - Upgraded to Virtualbox 5 -Linux Host -Windows XP guest

Tags: linux, windows-xp, virtualbox, audio

Since I upgraded to Virtualbox 5 the mute/volume in the Windows XP client has no effect.  If I want to mute something that is running in the virtual machine I have to mute my Linux Mint host. This is annoying. I could mute something in windows while still listening to sounds playing on the host before the upgrade. Other than downgrading, does anyone know how to fix this problem?